# Istio + minikube + Nginx (React). Cannot get access from browser nor CURL

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, istio

When I deploy without ingress-gateway I can get access via port-forwarding directly to LoadBalancer of application in the browser. But through ingress-gateway it not working.
Sidecars injection is enabled!

Istio v1.4.0
Minukube v1.5.2
Kubernetes v1.16.0

Istio instalation:

```
istioctl manifest apply \
  --set values.global.mtls.enabled=false \
  --set values.tracing.enabled=true \
  --set values.kiali.enabled=true \
  --set values.grafana.enabled=true \
--namespace istio-system
```

Than deploy React with NGINX.

```
# Frontend service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: front-web
  namespace: demo
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: front-web
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80

---
# Frontend app
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: front-web
  namespace: demo
  labels:
    app: front-web
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: front-web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: front-web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: front-web
        image: sergeygreat/front-web:v1.0.3
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Gateway

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: demo-gw
  namespace: demo
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: demo-vs
  namespace: demo
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - demo-gw
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 80
        host: front-web.default.svc.cluster.local  # <- tryed just `front-web`, no luck
```

```
>> kubectl get svc -n istio-system

istio-ingressgateway LoadBalancer 10.104.158.110 <pending> 80:31332/TCP,...
```

Everything is running but no access via http://minikube ip:31332 ???

For port 80 in browser: http://minikube_ip - `404 Not Found openresty/1.15.8.2`
For port 31332 in browser: http://minikube_ip:31332 - 503 Error

> > minikube ssh

```
$ curl -i http://localhost:31332
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
date: Mon, 16 Dec 2019 16:04:32 GMT
server: istio-envoy
content-length: 0

$ curl -i http://192.168.99.101:31332
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
date: Mon, 16 Dec 2019 16:04:45 GMT
server: istio-envoy
content-length: 0
```

Can please someone help?

Comment: service type should be nodeport or loadbalancer. Otherwise service is not accessible from outside. Then your ingress controller ( which is istio here) will have configuration to forward it to nodeport automatically

Comment: Changed to NodePort - but no effect  

`>>kubectl get svc -n demo
NAME       TYPE       CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/front-web   NodePort   10.111.178.244   <none>        9000:30255/TCP   47
`  

`
curl -i http://192.168.99.101:31332
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
date: Mon, 16 Dec 2019 16:29:09 GMT
server: istio-envoy
content-length: 0
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to recreate minikube:

```
>>minikube stop
>>minikube delete
>>minikube start --memory=16384 --cpus=4 --vm-driver=virtualbox --kubernetes-version=v1.16.0
```

If not help try to bind to another port:

```
- Deployment set to 80
- Service type should be NodePort and bind it to port 8080 targetPort:80
- VirtualService host "*" port 8080
```

It should work!

If not try to remove this part from VirtualService:

```
- match:
    - uri:
        exact: /
```

Comment: can you please provide the updated/corrected yaml? I am a bit confused. By virtual service port, you mean the destination port right?

Answer (score 0):

After you have set up your ingress, run minikube service . this will start the traffic flow over the minikube identified nodeport for HTTP2.

Finally, you can access your application over the `minikubeIP:<nodeport>` identified by minikube. I struggled alot! official doc said to use minikube tunnel, but it fails.

Answer (score -1):

If you using nginx ingress below are the steps. I would assume there is similar way to enable istio ingress

```
minikube addons enable ingress
```

Check you ingress controller is running by verify output of below command

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system
nginx-ingress-controller-5984b97644-rnkrg   1/1       Running   0          1m
```

Expose the service as nodeport. Below is example command

```
kubectl expose deployment web --target-port=8080 --type=NodePort

kubectl get service web
web       NodePort   10.104.133.249   <none>        8080:31637/TCP   12m
```

Then get the minikube url

```
minikube service web --url
http://172.17.0.15:31637
```

Comment: Did all that you suggest. But doesn't work.   

`front-web   NodePort 8080:30438/TCP`
`minikube service front-web -n demo --url`
`http://192.168.99.101:30438`

`curl -i http://192.168.99.101:30438`
`HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable`
`server: istio-envoy`
`x-envoy-decorator-operation: front-web.demo.svc.cluster.local:8080/*`

`upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure`

Comment: This link has got information for setting istio on minikube. https://medium.com/@jobinesh/setting-up-istio-on-minikube-for-running-bookinfo-demo-application-af25dab2a732 .  It suggests setting these things export INGRESS_HOST=$(minikube ip)
export INGRESS_PORT=$(kubectl -n istio-system get service istio-ingressgateway -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports[?(@.name=="http2")].nodePort}')
export SECURE_INGRESS_PORT=$(kubectl -n istio-system get service istio-ingressgateway -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports[?(@.name=="https")].nodePort}') .  export GATEWAY_URL=$INGRESS_HOST:$INGRESS_PORT

Comment: This is probably a valid answer, but to a different question – the Istio ingress gateway is separate from the Kubernetes Ingress object, and both are different from accessing a service via a NodePort Service.

Comment: @Shambu not all this doesn't help! I tried many tutorials including you provided

Comment: It seems the issue is not  about reaching istio gateway, it is istio gateway can't reach the backend which is webapp here.  The match uri and host information in virtual service definition doesn't seem to be  honoured. I see you using cluster wide qualifed name, so that should be reachable.  If you could post logs from istio, that may come of help